# How should openvpn config look like to tunnel "all traffic" thru vpn?

Tags: openvpn, traffic, tunneling, ipcop, windows

Many related questions on this site, looked thru a few of them, none helped my problem. Anyways my client is Vista, server is IPCop

My client config file:

```
#OpenVPN Server conf
tls-client
client
dev tun
proto udp
tun-mtu 1400
remote ip.to.server.here. 1194
pkcs12 NameOfPrettyPerson.p12
cipher BF-CBC
verb 3
ns-cert-type server
```

My problem is that not all traffic is routed thru the vpn,  I want all my traffic going thru our vpn, or having the option to do soo.

Basically my ip should be the ip of our server when browsing the web, not my clients ip. I can do this with a simple ssh tunnel to one of the server within the internal network, but the vpn seems to work differently.. I must be missing some knowledge here on how vpn works.

Should be a simple client config thing, right?  like "route all traffic thru vpn",  I'm unable to find anything similar in openvpn gui, or the config file. Help needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for **redirect-gateway** option.

check [this](http://manoftoday.wordpress.com/2006/12/03/openvpn-20-howto/) out.

Comment: You can have it. My brain isn't functioning yet ;)

Comment: @Dan C. lol.. can you anyway post your option? i noticed it was something else but did not bothered to check it... and now when it's gone curiosity kicked in.

Comment: It was the same as yours. It just left my fingers in a different permutation!

Comment: mm, figured it was some kinda server setting, thanks!